# LinkedList remove(), next, prev and head

Tags: java

I need to remove() from a (custom) LinkedList, setting last iterated item to null. There are two cases, one where prev is head, one where it is not. The nodes are next, prev and head. I was wondering if you spot any problems in the following code? Do I need to set the iterator variables in between? (or will emptying prev do the trick?) Thanks guys!

```
public void remove() { 
if(prev == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
else {
    if(prev == head){
        head = head.next;
        prev = null;
        sizeOfList--;
        }
    else {
        prev = null;
        sizeOfList--;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This situation is simple enough to exhaustively cover in unit tests - remove on a list of one item (victim is head), remove the tail of a list with two items (victim's prev is head), remove the tail of a list with three items (victim's prev is internal). I strongly suggest you do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your previous is not the head(second case in your code) you should fix the next link of the previous node before `prev`. Otherwise it will be left pointing to `prev`.

Comment: Hi Ivaylo, thanks for the answer! I understand how to make a prev node (last next, i.e prev = next). But how do I write the node before prev? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You will have to keep track of this element while iterating over your list. An alternative is to change the function to remove the current, not the previous element in which case you will only need prev and the current node.

Comment: Hi Ivaylo, I managed to find it! My only question now, which out of the following is unneccessary to update (In the If head clause: head -> head.next, next -> head, prev -> head).......and else clause: beforeprev.next -> prev.next, prev -> prev.next, next -> prev. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: I do not understand what are you asking, really. Sorry

Comment: In the else clause, what should next be?

Comment: Anyway, I got it working now. Thank you Ivaylo. I would vote up if I could, thanks!!!!! You're great